# Unable to view events from socketio to browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, innerhtml

I have an html client, thats listening for events from a JS server. I can confirm that on the client in the browser I receive the events, however, they do not show up in the UI. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>&#128293; Test Events</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <div id='timeline'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var events = []
      const socket = io()
      socket.on('test', function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        events.push(data)
        trimmed = events.slice(Math.max(events.length - 30, 1))
        html = trimmed.reverse().map(function(data){
          return `<div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <h3 class="media-heading">Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">${data}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>`
        }).join('')
        $("#timeline")[0].innerHTML  = html
      }, false)
    </script>
```

Comment: `trimmed` is always an empty array. `var events = []; events.push('something'); trimmed = events.slice(1); trimmed.length === 0`

Comment: Thanks for calling that out. I solved that issue by moving the events array outside of the socket listener. Now I just get return "object, Object" to the screen instead of the actual object values

Comment: You could do something like `${data.propertyName}` or if you want to output the whole object `${JSON.stringify(data)}` (one gets "[object Object]" if an object is converted to a string e.g. `'a' + {}`)